# PHP index.php for all links

Tags: php, indexing

So I have tried to copy this website over to my server because I want a local version of it to play around with. But I think I have missed a step in the configuration. The MySQL database and everything works fine, however the website works in the way that when you click a link you get redirected to

`/var/var2/var3/` then the `index.php` takes all of these vars and gives you a result.

The problem for me is that when I click the link on my local version, then the server actually tries to go to `/var/var2/var3/` and tells me that there is no such directory.

I believe this was done for SEO purposes. But how do I fix this on my local version?

Comment: There may be a `.htaccess` file that you didn't copy over?

Comment: Correct. But I see that the htaccess file won't trasnfer unless I name it. How do I rename it on linux so that it has no name? If I do the mv command then it just gets removed.

Comment: Actually, it makes it hidden. But it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ok so I noticed that the directory for it was incorrect in the apache2.conf so I fixed that. But also I came to think of the formatting on it.

As it's use to xxxx.com/var/var2/var3/ now it's xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/var/var2/var3/

Guessing that this line has to be changed somehow.

RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|php|psd|pdf|ico|js|swf|avi|mpeg|qt|flv)$ index.php